# reset user password in wso2 using admin service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

could you tell me how to reset password for a user in wso2 api manager(1.10) using admin services. I tried looking in internet but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

The password can be reset using the 'changePasswordByUser' operation from the 'UserAdmin' admin service.

More information on using admin services can be found from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+Admin+Services.

Accessing admin services with SoapUI using HTTP basic authentication is described in this [blog](http://sashimw.blogspot.com/2017/07/working-with-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i think for 'changePasswordByUser' we need to give user old password. But i want to use resetUserPassword as I user will forget their passwords. Could you provide me exact soap request and admin service name

Comment: Using the 'changePassword' operation you can reset the password of a user without providing the old password